# Java Regular Expression - Nested Object

Tags: java, regex

I am using Regular Expression in java to separate out groups in nested object as shown below.

```
properties={
    prop1={boolean=null, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=integer, short=null, integer=1, float=null, long=null}, 
    prop2={boolean=null, string=appId=854*tmp=159347540*temp4=469db7a0-d416-4fa5-856e-e26c33532559d*ts=1604594951147*btid=130324792*guid=72ee83438-6ece-40a4-9da4-2712fb296977*exitguid=13*unresolvedexitid=15015439*cidfrom=32324647*etypeorder=JMS*esubtype=JMS*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][150342]}, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
    prop3={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
    prop4={boolean=null, string=TEST, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
    prop5={boolean=null, string=TEST2, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
    prop6={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}
}
```

The output I am trying to get is

```
Group1 ---> prop1={boolean=null, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=integer, short=null, integer=1, float=null, long=null}, 
Group2 ---> prop2={boolean=null, string=appId=854*tmp=159347540*temp4=469db7a0-d416-4fa5-856e-e26c33532559d*ts=1604594951147*btid=130324792*guid=72ee83438-6ece-40a4-9da4-2712fb296977*exitguid=13*unresolvedexitid=15015439*cidfrom=32324647*etypeorder=JMS*esubtype=JMS*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][150342]}, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
Group3 ---> prop3={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
Group4 ---> prop4={boolean=null, string=TEST, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
Group5 --->prop5={boolean=null, string=TEST2, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, 
Group6 ---> prop6={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}
```

I have tried the expressions below

```
(s*={[^{[]*})+
(\w+={[^{[]+})+
```

Because of complexity of string in **Prop2**, my expression ignores **Prop2**. How can I update my expression to capture Prop2 as well.

Comment: sounds like you don't want regex, but a normal parser for your structured data.

Comment: Either of your regex are valid. Eg you haven’t escaped the braces. Please correct them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Example seems overly trivial (simply split on newlines and chop off the first and last lines) but it's easy to see how the problem can fail to be parseable by a nonrecursive regular expression as soon as a group becomes multiline. Please provide more information to make the computational class discernable here.

Comment: What kind of nesting are you looking for ? Some individual `prop={` lines have nesting. And the outer `properties={` has all those inner ones. How can you define where to start ?

Comment: Just pay attention to the group 0 match data `(?s)prop\d+=(?={)(?:(?=.*?{(?!.*?\1)(.*}(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?}(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^{]*(?=\2$)` https://regex101.com/r/7gYJXu/1

Comment: How about this regex : `(?:prop\d+=)({.+})`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIUokO/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
\w+=\{.*\}
```

Dot doesn’t match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

**This might help:**

Using Pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\s+(\\w+=\\{.*\\},)", Pattern.MULTILINE)
```

Pattern in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "properties={\n"
            + "    prop1={boolean=null, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=integer, short=null, integer=1, float=null, long=null}, \n"
            + "    prop2={boolean=null, string=appId=854*tmp=159347540*temp4=469db7a0-d416-4fa5-856e-e26c33532559d*ts=1604594951147*btid=130324792*guid=72ee83438-6ece-40a4-9da4-2712fb296977*exitguid=13*unresolvedexitid=15015439*cidfrom=32324647*etypeorder=JMS*esubtype=JMS*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][150342]}, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, \n"
            + "    prop3={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, \n"
            + "    prop4={boolean=null, string=TEST, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, \n"
            + "    prop5={boolean=null, string=TEST2, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}, \n"
            + "    prop6={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null}\n"
            + "}";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\s+(\\w+=\\{.*\\},)", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    result.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Output:

```
prop1={boolean=null, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=integer, short=null, integer=1, float=null, long=null},
prop2={boolean=null, string=appId=854*tmp=159347540*temp4=469db7a0-d416-4fa5-856e-e26c33532559d*ts=1604594951147*btid=130324792*guid=72ee83438-6ece-40a4-9da4-2712fb296977*exitguid=13*unresolvedexitid=15015439*cidfrom=32324647*etypeorder=JMS*esubtype=JMS*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][150342]}, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null},
prop3={boolean=true, string=null, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=boolean, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null},
prop4={boolean=null, string=TEST, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null},
prop5={boolean=null, string=TEST2, byte=null, double=null, propertyType=string, short=null, integer=null, float=null, long=null},
```